# t-sql output of updated results

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

How can I print the rows updated by this query in this query:

```
update
    Table1.RecommendationLeg 
set 
    actualValue = ( leg.actualprice * str.currentSize)
from
    Table1.RecommendationLeg leg  
    inner join Recommendation str 
        on leg.partofId = str.id
where 
    leg.actualValue = 0 
    and datediff( n, timeOf, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) > 30
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you on?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
update
    Table1.RecommendationLeg 
set 
    actualValue = ( leg.actualprice * str.currentSize)
OUTPUT INSERTED.actualValue -- <-- this. Edit, after SET not UPDATE. Oops. Sorry.
from
    Table1.RecommendationLeg leg  
    inner join Recommendation str 
        on leg.partofId = str.id
where 
    leg.actualValue = 0 
    and datediff( n, timeOf, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) > 30
```

Comment: This is it, but the OUTPUT goes in the SET.  I was having trouble until I realized that INSERTED was Table1.RecommendationLeg.  You can do stuff like "OUTPUT INSERTED.actualValue as av, inserted.actualPrice as ap, str.currentSize as cs"

Answer (score 3):

If you are on SQL Server 2005 and above, you can use the [`OUTPUT` clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx).